# How Follow function works? (compiler)

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

Grammar:

```
E -> TE’
E’ -> +TE’ | ε
T -> FΤ’
Τ’ -> *FΤ’ | ε
F -> (E)| id
```

Functions:

```
1. FIRST(F) = FIRST(T) = FIRST(E) = {(, id}
2. FIRST(E’) = {+, ε}
3. FIRST(T’) = {*, ε}
4. FOLLOW(E) = FOLLOW(E’) = {), $}
5. FOLLOW(T) = FOLLOW(T’) = {+, ), $}
6. FOLLOW(F) = {*, +, ), $}
```

Here is the grammar and the functions from my lectures...Can someone explain me how **FOLLOW** works??? I understood how FIRST work but FOLLOW is very difficult to understand...

Comment: What type of grammar is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Wikipedia's FIRST_and_FOLLOW_sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser#FIRST_and_FOLLOW_sets)
.

#### FOLLOW(E):

You look for any references of `E`.
Here `(E)` and union all following terminals and the FIRST-set of the following nonterminals.
Here only the following terminal `)`.

#### FOLLOW(F):

`F` is referenced by `FT`, `*FT'`. So `FOLLOW(F)` is the union of `FIRST(T) = {(, id}*` and `FIRST(T') = {*, ε}`.

Finally, `FOLLOW(F) = {(, id, *, ε}`.

Answer (score 1):

here FOLLOW(F) is find by this way:
T-->FT'  means FOLLOW(T) IS subset of FOLLOW(F)
T'-->*FT' means FIRST(T') contain epsilon then except epsilon and add other values to set.